# Connection Settings in IE changes after every system restart

Tags: windows-7, networking, proxy, internet-explorer

I changed the settings in IE to not to use proxy server for connections by unchecking the

> Tools->Internet Options->Connections tab->Settings->`Use a proxy server for this connection`

But Whenever I restart my windows 7, Internet Explorer changes its setting back again to use the proxy server settings. So in other browsers such as Firefox or Chrome some website are not loading and shows a page which shows only the message `Error`.

So I need to uncheck the checkbox every time I restart my Computer.
And my Eclipse software does not connects to the internet to download the neccessay files to start my jetty server. So I need to disconnect the internet and wait for the server to start after throwing some error message about connection problem and I have to reconnect the internet connection to use it back again.

So how do I set a global setting in Windows 7 to apply to all application to not use a proxy while connecting to Internet.?Or How to bypass the Internet Explorer connection settings and tell a software application to use its own internet connection setting and not the one mentioned in my IE browser?

Comment: Are you using a local or domain user account?

Comment: @Ramhound i cant understand..if its about user accounts, Yes I m using a local and I am logged in using the admin account..there is no other user account..

Comment: The reason I asked the question is this.  Your local account can be an Administrator but if its actually a domain account your logging into, the permissions are handled by the domain, which means a local Administrator account could have a great deal of restrictions place on it including the restoration of certain domain polciies after a restart.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I understand what you mean but no one has control over my computer so i hope thats not a problem..do you have any solution to solve this problem?or what do you think might be a problem with my settings?

Comment: Well if you are sure this computer is not connected to a domain, i would create myself a new user profile, and verify the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: @Ramhound i installed the latest windows 7 Service Pack 1..but the problem still exists.. can u reproduce the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Use the registry key:

```
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

to set the binding of:

```
ProxySettingsPerUser
```

to:

```
1
```

in order to persist your settings.

In addition, set:

```
ProxyEnable
```

to 0.

As an alternative, add a list of sites to the Internet Zone which bypasses the proxy as a workaround:

- Internet Options => Security => Local Intranet
- Click Advanced
- Put a site you access in the text field, such as:

  ```
    *://*.superuser.com
  ```
- Click `Add`
- Repeat for others, such as:

  ```
    *://*.stackoverflow.com
    *://*.stackexchange.com
  ```

Or create a script to generate the list and append it to the following file:

```
file://c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/proxy
```

**References**

- [Internet Explorer security zones registry entries for advanced users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/browsers/ie-security-zones-registry-entries)
- [Registry Reference: Disable changing proxy settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc787305%28v=ws.10%29)
- [How to Use Wild Cards When You Add Web Sites to Security Zones](https://web.archive.org/web/20150225212607/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/184456)
- [Understanding security zones](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913224909/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/zone_ovr.mspx)
- [Understanding Web Proxy Configuration](https://web.archive.org/web/20160225223437/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/10/11/web-proxy-configuration-and-ie11-changes.aspx?)
- [The Local Intranet Zone and Proxies: The Surprising Connection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/)
- [How to strengthen the security settings for the Local Machine zone in Internet Explorer](https://web.archive.org/web/20150305195942/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/833633)

Comment: thanks for the answer..but however I reinstalled my windows and now that everthing is working properly..so i could not try this solution..